# What is difference between [pool release] and [pool drain]?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between sending -release or -drain to an Autorelease Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797419/whats-the-difference-between-sending-release-or-drain-to-an-autorelease-pool)

I just got always wondered about difference between [pool release] and [pool drain]..

When we create a View-based application in IOS, use [pool release].

When we create a command-line Tool in MAX OS X, use [pool drain].

why do use them differently?

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> In a garbage-collected environment, there is no need for autorelease
>   pools. You may, however, write a framework that is designed to work in
>   both a garbage-collected and reference-counted environment. In this
>   case, you can use autorelease pools to hint to the collector that
>   collection may be appropriate. In a garbage-collected environment,
>   sending a drain message to a pool triggers garbage collection if
>   necessary; release, however, is a no-op. In a reference-counted
>   environment, drain has the same effect as release. Typically,
>   therefore, you should use drain instead of release.

Answer (score 6):

No difference unless you're using Garbage Collection on OSX.  Exactly the same on iOS and OSX w/o GC.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

joe