# release objects in multithreading

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, memory-leaks, nsthread

Suppose I create a new thread and passes an object to it. How to release it?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    float x=    scrollView.contentOffset.x/(self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 40 );
    int pg=round(x);
    pg=abs(x);
    currentPage=pg;
    if(pg!=currentIndex && pg+1 < pageCounter)
    {
        currentIndex=   pg; 
        NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInt:pg+1];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getImageForPage:) toTarget:self withObject:num];
    }
}
```

//here goes a background job

```
-(void)getImageForPage:(NSNumber*)page{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int pg=[page intValue];
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[scrl viewWithTag:pg];
    UIImageView *imgV = (UIImageView *)[btn viewWithTag:1111];      
    if(imgV.image==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"currnt visible page %d ",currentPage);
        if(!isWorking)
        {
        UIImage *im=    [self imageFromPDFforPage:pg+1];        
            imgV.image = im;
        }
        else
            [self performSelector:@selector(getImageForPage:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pg+1] afterDelay:3];
    }
    [pool drain];
}
```

shall I call [pool drain]; or [pool release];

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromPDFforPage:(int)page {
    isWorking=YES;
    CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, page);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);  
    NSLog(@"page %d, w=  %f h= %f",page, pageRect.size.width,pageRect.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(pageRect),CGRectGetMaxY(pageRect));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);  
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(pageRect.origin.x), -(pageRect.origin.y));     
    CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox),
                                            CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context));
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);     
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    isWorking=NO;
    return finalImage;          
}
```

My understanding is this function is also called in background threads. Here pdf is class variable. 
am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey saurabh you can call `[pool release]` or `[pool drain]`. You can check the documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Or check this answer for extra info:

[What's the difference between sending -release or -drain to an Autorelease Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797419/whats-the-difference-between-sending-release-or-drain-to-an-autorelease-pool)

Answer (score 0):

(1) In a non-garbage-collected environment `[pool drain]` and `[pool release]` behave the same.

(2) The object you are passing in the separate thread is an autoreleased object, so you do not need to release it in `scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`.

As an aside, if you are targeting a version of iOS that supports GCD, you way want to use that technology as opposed to threads.

Comment: yeah thats true its an autoreleased object but what if its not?

Comment: From the NSThread docs, the object passed to the thread are retained then released at the end of execution.